# error al recorrer json con javascript o jquery (Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:)

Tags: javascript, jquery

mi codigo y las diferentes formas que utilize pero marca error

```
    <script>
function cargarEspecialidades(){
    var especialidadCambio2 = document.getElementById("especialidad1");
    var listar = 'listar';
    $.ajax(
        {
          data:{especialidad_id : especialidadCambio2.value, accion : listar},
            url:   "ins_doctor.php",
            type:  "GET",
            success:  function (data) 
            {
              $(data).each(function(i, v){ // indice, valor
                $("#especialidad2").append('<option value="' + v.idEspecialidad + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');
            })
              //console.log(data);
              //data= data;
              //console.log(data.idEspecialidad);
              /*for(var registro in data){
                console.log(registro);
                //$("#especialidad2").append('<option value='+registro.idEspecialidad+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
              }*/
              /*$.each(data,function(key, registro) {
                $("#especialidad2").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
              });*/
            }
        });
}
</script>
```

mi json

```
[{"idEspecialidad":"1","nombre":"Alergologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"2","nombre":"Anestesiologia y reanimacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"4","nombre":"Gastroenterologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"5","nombre":"Endocrinologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"6","nombre":"Geriatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"7","nombre":"Hematologia y hemoterapia"},{"idEspecialidad":"8","nombre":"Infectologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"9","nombre":"Medicina aeroespacial"},{"idEspecialidad":"10","nombre":"Medicina del deporte"},{"idEspecialidad":"11","nombre":"Medicina del trabajo"},{"idEspecialidad":"12","nombre":"Medicina de urgencias"},{"idEspecialidad":"13","nombre":"Medicina familiar y comunitaria"},{"idEspecialidad":"14","nombre":"Medicina fisica y rehabilitacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"15","nombre":"Medicina intensiva"},{"idEspecialidad":"16","nombre":"Medicina interna"},{"idEspecialidad":"17","nombre":"Medicina legal y forense"},{"idEspecialidad":"18","nombre":"Medicina preventiva y salud publica"},{"idEspecialidad":"19","nombre":"Medicina veterinaria"},{"idEspecialidad":"20","nombre":"Nefrologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"21","nombre":"Neumologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"22","nombre":"Neurologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"23","nombre":"Nutriologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"24","nombre":"Oftalmologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"25","nombre":"Oncologia medica"},{"idEspecialidad":"26","nombre":"Oncologia radioterapica"},{"idEspecialidad":"27","nombre":"Pediatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"28","nombre":"Psiquiatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"29","nombre":"Rehabilitacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"30","nombre":"Reumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"31","nombre":"Toxicologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"32","nombre":"Urologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"33","nombre":"Cirugia cardiovascular"},{"idEspecialidad":"34","nombre":"Cirugia general y del aparato digestivo"},{"idEspecialidad":"35","nombre":"Cirugia oral y maxilofacial"},{"idEspecialidad":"36","nombre":"Cirugia ortopedica y traumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"37","nombre":"Cirugia pediatrica"},{"idEspecialidad":"38","nombre":"Cirugia plastica, estetica y reparadora"},{"idEspecialidad":"39","nombre":"Cirugia toracica"},{"idEspecialidad":"40","nombre":"Neurocirugia"},{"idEspecialidad":"41","nombre":"Angiologia y cirugia vascular"},{"idEspecialidad":"42","nombre":"Dermatologia medico-quirurgica y venereologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"43","nombre":"Oftalmologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"44","nombre":"Otorrinolaringologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"45","nombre":"Urologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"46","nombre":"Traumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"47","nombre":"Ginecologia y obstetrica o tocologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"48","nombre":"Analisis clinicos"},{"idEspecialidad":"49","nombre":"Anatomia patologica"},{"idEspecialidad":"50","nombre":"Bioquimica clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"51","nombre":"Farmacologia clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"52","nombre":"Genetica medica"},{"idEspecialidad":"53","nombre":"Inmunologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"54","nombre":"Medicina nuclear"},{"idEspecialidad":"55","nombre":"Microbiologia y parasitologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"56","nombre":"Neurofisiologia clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"57","nombre":"Radiodiagnostico o radiologia"}]
```

el select que quiero llenar

```
<div class="input-field col s4 m4">
                                <i class="material-icons prefix">especialidad 2</i>
                                <select name="especialidad2" id="especialidad2" >
                                </select>  
                                <label for="especialidad2"><?php echo 'Especialidad 2' ?></label>
                            </div>

error jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"idEspecialidad":"1","nombre":"Alergologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"2","nombre":"Anestesiologia y reanimacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"4","nombre":"Gastroenterologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"5","nombre":"Endocrinologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"6","nombre":"Geriatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"7","nombre":"Hematologia y hemoterapia"},{"idEspecialidad":"8","nombre":"Infectologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"9","nombre":"Medicina aeroespacial"},{"idEspecialidad":"10","nombre":"Medicina del deporte"},{"idEspecialidad":"11","nombre":"Medicina del trabajo"},{"idEspecialidad":"12","nombre":"Medicina de urgencias"},{"idEspecialidad":"13","nombre":"Medicina familiar y comunitaria"},{"idEspecialidad":"14","nombre":"Medicina fisica y rehabilitacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"15","nombre":"Medicina intensiva"},{"idEspecialidad":"16","nombre":"Medicina interna"},{"idEspecialidad":"17","nombre":"Medicina legal y forense"},{"idEspecialidad":"18","nombre":"Medicina preventiva y salud publica"},{"idEspecialidad":"19","nombre":"Medicina veterinaria"},{"idEspecialidad":"20","nombre":"Nefrologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"21","nombre":"Neumologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"22","nombre":"Neurologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"23","nombre":"Nutriologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"24","nombre":"Oftalmologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"25","nombre":"Oncologia medica"},{"idEspecialidad":"26","nombre":"Oncologia radioterapica"},{"idEspecialidad":"27","nombre":"Pediatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"28","nombre":"Psiquiatria"},{"idEspecialidad":"29","nombre":"Rehabilitacion"},{"idEspecialidad":"30","nombre":"Reumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"31","nombre":"Toxicologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"32","nombre":"Urologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"33","nombre":"Cirugia cardiovascular"},{"idEspecialidad":"34","nombre":"Cirugia general y del aparato digestivo"},{"idEspecialidad":"35","nombre":"Cirugia oral y maxilofacial"},{"idEspecialidad":"36","nombre":"Cirugia ortopedica y traumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"37","nombre":"Cirugia pediatrica"},{"idEspecialidad":"38","nombre":"Cirugia plastica, estetica y reparadora"},{"idEspecialidad":"39","nombre":"Cirugia toracica"},{"idEspecialidad":"40","nombre":"Neurocirugia"},{"idEspecialidad":"41","nombre":"Angiologia y cirugia vascular"},{"idEspecialidad":"42","nombre":"Dermatologia medico-quirurgica y venereologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"43","nombre":"Oftalmologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"44","nombre":"Otorrinolaringologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"45","nombre":"Urologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"46","nombre":"Traumatologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"47","nombre":"Ginecologia y obstetrica o tocologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"48","nombre":"Analisis clinicos"},{"idEspecialidad":"49","nombre":"Anatomia patologica"},{"idEspecialidad":"50","nombre":"Bioquimica clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"51","nombre":"Farmacologia clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"52","nombre":"Genetica medica"},{"idEspecialidad":"53","nombre":"Inmunologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"54","nombre":"Medicina nuclear"},{"idEspecialidad":"55","nombre":"Microbiologia y parasitologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"56","nombre":"Neurofisiologia clinica"},{"idEspecialidad":"57","nombre":"Radiodiagnostico o radiologia"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes especificar que tu peticion es de tipo JSON by usar la funcion $.each() para iterar la respuesta

```
$.ajax(
    {
      data:{especialidad_id : especialidadCambio2.value, accion : listar},
        url:   "ins_doctor.php",
        type:  "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success:  function (data) 
        {
         $.each(data, function(i, v) {
            $("#especialidad2").append('<option value="' + v.idEspecialidad + '">' + v.nombre + '</option>');
        })
          //console.log(data);
          //data= data;
          //console.log(data.idEspecialidad);
          /*for(var registro in data){
            console.log(registro);
            //$("#especialidad2").append('<option value='+registro.idEspecialidad+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
          }*/
          /*$.each(data,function(key, registro) {
            $("#especialidad2").append('<option value='+registro.id+'>'+registro.nombre+'</option>');
          });*/
        }
    });
```

Comment: me marca error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"idEspecialidad":"1","nombre...........................................

Comment: cierto, edite mi respuesta

Comment: ahora es diferente el error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"idEspecialidad":"1","nombre":"Alergologia"},{"idEspecialidad":"3","nombre":"Cardiologia"},

Comment: agregaste el  `  dataType: 'json',`?

Comment: data:{especialidad_id : especialidadCambio2.value, accion : listar},
            url:   "ins_doctor.php",
            type:  "GET",
            success:  function (data)

Comment: te falta esa linea que te digo

Comment: gracias ya quedo